# Find out Function type in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm

I am iterating over the Module's function lists as shown below.
I am seeking for a way to find out if a `Function *f` is a declaration or a definition. (By dumping the function it seems that the list contains the two types.)

```
for (Module::iterator f = M->begin(), fend = M->end(); f != fend; ++f) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [`Function`](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-function-class) manual:

> If the `BasicBlock` list is empty, this indicates that the `Function` is actually a function declaration: the actual body of the function hasn’t been linked in yet.

and in the next section on [Important Public Members of the Function](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#important-public-members-of-the-function), you'll find the function you want:

> bool [`isDeclaration`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#a4640d98233102674ddb6d6efaf2b7f97)()
>
> Return whether or not the Function has a body defined. If the function is “external”, it does not have a body, and thus must be resolved by linking with a function defined in a different translation unit.

which does the emptiness check for you.

Comment: I see that another function isDeclarationForLinker() is similar but different. What is the difference between these two functions?